# Unwind Segue into an NSMutable Array

Tags: objective-c, iphone, nsmutablearray, tableview, segue

I am having some trouble getting my data from an unwind segue into a NSMutableArray object. When I do an NSLog out of the unwind segue, it shows that the information is there, it just does not end up in my array to show in the table view. What is my problem? Thanks everyone.

```
#import "ChoicesViewController.h"
#import "MyDataChoices.h"
#import "AddChoiceViewController.h"

@interface ChoicesViewController () <UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *myTableView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *arrayNames;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *sections;
@end

@implementation ChoicesViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.myTableView.delegate = self;
    self.myTableView.dataSource = self;
    self.sections = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"A", @"B", @"C", @"D", @"E", @"F", @"G", @"H", @"I", @"J", @"K", @"L", @"M", @"N", @"O", @"P", @"Q", @"R", @"S", @"T", @"U", @"V,", @"W", @"X", @"Y", @"Z", nil];

    self.arrayNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [self.arrayNames addObjectsFromArray:@[
                                         [MyDataChoices itemWithNewName:@"Apples"],
                                         [MyDataChoices itemWithNewName:@"Bread"]]];
}

- (IBAction)unwindSegueToChoices:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
{

    AddChoiceViewController *sourceVC = segue.sourceViewController;
    NSString *myNewItem = sourceVC.myTextField.text;
    //NSString *myFinalString = [[myNewItem substringToIndex:1] capitalizedString];
    NSString *capitalizedString = [myNewItem capitalizedString];
    NSLog(capitalizedString);
    //Why will this not work?
    [self.arrayNames addObject:capitalizedString];

}

-(NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *) tableView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *) tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.arrayNames.count;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MyDataChoices *currentRow = self.arrayNames[indexPath.row];
    UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"mainCell2" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.text = currentRow.myNameChoices;
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: So if you log self.arrayNames as the last line in the unwindSegueToChoices does it show that capitalizedString was not added (or are you just not seeing it in your table view)?

Answer (score 1):

You need to reload the table view after adding the new item to the array:

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```